# private/protect/public in construct()

Tags: php, laravel

I have a Laravel 9 with php 8.1.10, windows.

app\Domains\Ocadmin\Http\Controllers\User\UserController.php

[image]

Now, I create a new Laravel 10 with php 8.2.5

[image]

There is an error message says

```
syntax error, unexpected 'private' (T_PRIVATE), expecting variable (T_VARIABLE)
```

[image]

I compared the two projects, can't figure out what's the problem. But the page still works.

Comment: Maybe the language level of the IDE has changed to something lower than PHP 8?

Comment: Yes, this is ide error. Sync language level with composer is settings

Comment: It's the issue: https://php.watch/versions/8.2/dynamic-properties-deprecated